# Can i add a 13.04 repo to 12.04 LTS to install new package via synaptic?

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt

I want to install julia (programming language from MIT) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I encountered some problems with the compilation from source. I noticed that there is a specific package to install it on 13.04 via aptitude. Can I add the corresponding repo in 12.04 without creating conflicts ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the package here:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/julia/download

and then try to install it with a terminal command:

```
dpkg -i ./julia_0.1.2+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

If it failes due to dependencies, install gdebi and try:

```
gdebi ./julia_0.1.2+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to simply add a repository with a future distribution: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main` to your sources.list, you will probably run into dependency errors. To mix repositories, use pinning: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto.

If you are trying to upgrade a package supported by Canonical, you can check if it has been backported to Ubuntu 12.04. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports.

Answer (score 0):

To install Julia, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install julia
```